# Using Blender's GUI application from WSL2 (repost from stackoverflow)

Tags: windows, opengl, linux

**This is a repost from StackOverflow, I was recommend to post this here by a friend**

Recently a fellow intern finished his internship. For this internship, he wrote some automated fluid simulations in Blender on Linux. I am a Windows user, and my only option for this is running WSL(2).
Everything runs great, except for the last step (which is most important to my work). This last step requires the Blender GUI to run.

I am currently using VcXrsv, installed by following this tutorial: https://dannyda.com/2020/06/15/how-to-launch-gui-software-programs-from-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2-wsl2-how-to-convert-from-wsl-1-to-wsl-2/. I have made sure to allow native OpenGL.

I've managed to run other GUI applications using this x-server , but Blender will not run, instead giving me this error:

```
Read prefs: /home/pcsmet/.config/blender/2.90/config/userpref.blend
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4732:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5220:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Error! Unsupported graphics card or driver.
A graphics card and driver with support for OpenGL 3.3 or higher is required.
The program will now close.
Error: Not freed memory blocks: 14567, total unfreed memory 5.376877 MB
```

I've read about being able to use your (nvidia) graphics card if you enter the Windows Insiders build + install nvidia's special WSL2 drivers, but I've also read some forum posts about OpenGL not working on WSL2. Also, I'm afraid of Win10's updates' ability to brick pc's, so I'd prefer not to enter the Windows Insiders programme.

Simply, my questions is this: **Is it possible to run Blender GUI through WSL2, and if so, how?**

I am far from a Linux/WSL wizzkid, and getting this to work is fairly vital to my internship, so any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

**edit**
The last step is generating computer vision notations (instance masks for the fluid outline). The method the other intern implemented requires a viewport. As far as I know, the library he used only runs on Linux.

Comment: Take a step back, in what aspect that simulation process cannot run in windows? Can't the program "save" the simulation result in exchangeable format for windows Blender to use? If you are not familiar with Linux, using WSL2 will only make you more difficult to reproduce the code from his work.

Comment: Please check the edit @HikariTW, thank you!